# Making a div invisible & stable while js is off

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a `<div>` that is part of a form.

It's a red circle. When I disable JS it remains shown (I know I can use `display: none` to fix that).

The problem is that when I enable JS again , on the user interaction my `<div>` goes one line down (it doesn't maintain it's original position).

That annoys me because I have input fields and the div is at the end of every div ... So what I want (if it's possible is to make the div not display on js/off and not to jump a line down when on js/on & user interacction...

HTML:

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
  <head>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.0.0-alpha1.js"></script>
<meta charset="utf-8">
 <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>

 <div id="name1" >
         <input type="text" id="namebox" placeholder="First name* ..."name="name">
         <div class="span1">!</div>
         </div> 
         <div id="name2" >
         <input type="text" id="namebox1" placeholder="Last name* ..." name="surname">
          <div class="span1">!</div>
         </div> 
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"  type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

CSS:

```
 .span1{
 background-color: white;
 color: red;
 height: 28px;
 width: 28px;
 font-size: 0.6em;
 margin-right: 1px;
 margin-bottom:2px;
 line-height: 30px;
 text-align: center;
 text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.2);
 border-radius: 100%;
 border:2px solid red;
 display:inline-block;
 font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
 }
```

JS:

```
$(".span1").hide();

function nameEvent(){
$(this).next().toggle($(this).val().length <=1);
}
$("#namebox").on("focus input", nameEvent);
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.   Although you have provided a link to an example, if the link were to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem.

Comment: When I change 'display:inlike-block' with 'display:none' it goes under the 'input' ?!

Comment: @Paulie_D  thank you for the warm welcome , should I post the code here also ?

Comment: See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I think  'display:none' puts the div into a new line because it's changing the position , when I change from  position:relative to absolute the same thing happens , but it's of no use because I want to use only 1 div , not to make many divs and set their perfect fit with top-bottom-left-right moving around ...

Comment: @Paulie_D I don't understant why people downvote post they don't know how to answere to , it's their ego hurt?

Comment: Because despite at least two references you haven't provided the relevant code **in the question** or a working demo. Read the comments in the reasons given why this is now on hold.

Comment: @Paulie_D here is the code https://jsbin.com/yucipuvuta/edit?html,css,js,output , are you people blind or what ?! it's written in the question also ...

Comment: `link in the question` !== `code in the question`. Attitude not appreciated.

Comment: AGAIN! The code has to be **in the question**...not a link which might rot and be of no use to future users.

Comment: I have an answer for you, which I'll be happy to provide if you meet the minimum requirements of SO's format.

Comment: @isherwood how can you say that ? it's the same thing !

Comment: @isherwood is it now ok ?

Comment: @A.Wolff I didn't understood the first time (the fact that the code must be posted here , on this platform ) my bad :(

Comment: @Paulie_D  I've made the changes is it ok now ?

Answer (score 0):

Add in your CSS file

```
#name{
position:relative;
}
```

and add a property
**position:absolute;** in .span1

so span1 will be look like this

```
.span1{
background-color: white;
  color: red;
  height: 28px;
  width: 28px;
  font-size: 0.6em;
  margin-right: 1px;
  margin-bottom:2px;
  line-height: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.2);
  border-radius: 100%;
  border:2px solid red;
  display:inline-block;
  font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
  position:absolute;
  }
```

Comment: what do you want to do? please elaborate

Comment: I want to the div to mentain it's position on js turned off , because I use js to hide/show it , and to do that (from what I know so far) you write display:none , insetad of inline-block in css , but when I do that , it goes a line down (the red cirle div) so it's not in the same position , that's the problem , that people who don't know the answer  downvote this post , shame on them... I though this a place of people , not of hate and ego...

Comment: I think you should use css visibility property instead of display property.
visibility:hidden;
visibility: visible;
try this

Comment: I don't want so set them to invisible , because otherwise I wouldn't be here anymore , I want them to be visible , the problem is the position-change , not the visibility status :)